# Transaction fees too high for swapExactETHForTokens

Tags: web3js, gas, gas-price, pancakeswap

I've written a script to buy tokens in javascript. The issue is I keep getting an error showing  abnormally high transaction fees. This is my script

```
const buyFunction = this.pancakeContract.methods.swapExactETHForTokens(
    this.w3HTTP.utils.toHex(this.w3HTTP.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')), // amountOutMin: set to 0 or calculate based on slippage
    [this.config.constants.liquidityPairAddress, tokenAddress], // path
    this.config.settings.walletAddress, // to: Recipient of the tokens
    Math.floor((Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 2) // deadline: Current time + 2 minutes
  )
  const nonce = await this.w3HTTP.eth.getTransactionCount(this.config.settings.walletAddress)
  const amount = this.w3HTTP.utils.toWei(amt, 'ether');
  
  const gasPrice = this.w3HTTP.utils.toWei('3', 'gwei');
  const gas = this.w3HTTP.utils.toHex(Number(config.settings.gasAmount));
  const walletBalance = await this.w3HTTP.eth.getBalance(this.config.settings.walletAddress);

  const rawTransaction = {
    "from": this.config.settings.walletAddress,
    "gas": this.w3HTTP.utils.toHex(gas),  // 250,000Wei
    "gasPrice": this.w3HTTP.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
    "to":this.config.constants.pancakeswapRouterAddress,
    "value":this.w3HTTP.utils.toHex(amount),
    "data":buyFunction.encodeABI(),
    "nonce":nonce
  };

  const signedTx = await this.w3HTTP.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, this.config.keys.walletPrivateKey);
  // console.log("signed tx: ", signedTx)

  const receipt = await this.w3HTTP.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction).catch(console.log);
```

When I run this, with an `amt` value of 0.0000001BNB I get the error

```
'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x700C9A0c93616918E2685b4cf5115e26C8d2DF74 have 23129168874516353 want 87741903484150489762066983472 (supplied gas 300000)'
```

Why do I get these abnormally high transaction fee? Could I be using the wrong units in the rawTransaction?

Answer (score 0):

When setting `amount`, I decided to set its type to Number like this

```
const amount = Number(this.w3HTTP.utils.toWei(amt, 'ether'));
```